# Git authentication as root from Python script doesn't work even when demoted

Tags: python, git, ssh

I have a Python script that needs to run in sudo mode and that should also run some git commands (among them clone and push). These commands can't connect to the server, because they are run as root and as such don't use my normal-user ssh key.

So far it's a common problem, but the thing is that I am already trying to demote the user before calling these commands. I used:

```
def bash_background_demoted(cmd_list):
    def _demote():
        if getuid() == 0:
            user = getenv('SUDO_USER')
        else:
            user = getenv('USER')
        uid, gid = pwd.getpwnam(user)[2:4]
        setegid(gid)
        seteuid(uid)

    process = Popen(cmd_list, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, preexec_fn = _demote)
    outp, err = process.communicate()
    print outp + err
```

This method seems to work on other commands, but not on git:

```
bash_background_demoted(['whoami'])
# mark
bash_background_demoted(['git', 'clone', 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/stuff', '/repo/dir/'])
# Permission denied (publickey).
# fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I don't run as sudo, it does work (but other parts break, so it's not an acceptable solution).

The -i [keyfile] argument doesn't exist for push. Anyone know a solution? Probably something trivial, but I'm stuck...

*EDIT:*
The HOME environment variable is set correctly in main process and the subprocess. USER isn't set correctly, but setting it doesn't change the error.

*EDIT2:*
I've verified it is really the keys causing the problem. I copies mine to /root/.ssh/ and the errors went away. Not a good solution though.

(The solution only needs to work on Ubuntu in a recent version of Python 2)

Comment: Stray thought / possibility: maybe `ssh` is using `$USER `in some undesirable way, so although `$HOME` is OK, it also needs `$USER` set to `mark`?

Comment: It is set as `root`, I changed it to `mark` (not sure if that's a good idea but ow well) but the problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

What is the `HOME` environment variable set to? Make sure it points to `mark`'s home and not `root`'s.

Comment: Good idea, but `os.getenv('HOME')` returns `/home/mark` in the main program and at the end of _demote

Comment: And `$HOME` is correct in a shell script run through `bash_background_demoted`